# Oracle APEX how to refer to values in other columns in a tabular form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle APEX tabular form with the following columns:

Project,Rater Group,Ratee,Min Persons,Max Persons

Project and Rater Group are select lists. When I select a value for Rater Group I would like to limit the Rater Groups to only those Rater Groups in the Project in the first column. However the column attributes does not have a cascading value similar to form fields. Is there any way of doing this?

I've tried:

- `project_id = apex_application.g_f03(:APEX$ROW_NUM)`
- `project_id = #PROJECT_ID#`
- `project_id = :PROJECT_ID`
- `project_id = apex_050000.wwv_flow_tabular_form.get_row_values`

none of which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this page which links to some nice examples of how to cascade within tabular forms:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2359498

The first link posted by 'Roel' shows a working example.